# Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'Object'

Tags: typescript, types, typescript2.0

Trying to implement functional pluck with a sound type, but I'm doing something wrong:

```
function pluck<Object extends {}, Key = keyof Object>(key: Key): (o: Object) => Object[Key] {
  return object => object[key];
}
```

TS error:

> Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'Object'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `Key extends keyof Object`:

```
function pluck<Object extends {}, Key extends keyof Object>(key: Key): (o: Object) => Object[Key] {
  return object => object[key];
}
```

The syntax `T = S` in a generic is specifying a default for the type but not constraining the type in any way.