# Default props in TypeScript React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I recently found a way to set default props on React components, like this:

```
type Props = {
  children: any,
  color?: keyof typeof textColors,
};

const GTitle: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, color }) => (
  <Title color={textColors[color]}>
    {children}
  </Title>
);

GTitle.defaultProps = {
  color: 'primary',
};
```

The problem is that even if I define that there is a default property, the TypeScript keeps accusing the possibility of having an undefined value, as in the example below:

[image]

Comment: Use actual default arguments, TypeScript understands them just fine: `= ({ children, color = "primary" }) =>`

Comment: Indeed, `defaultProps` will [eventually go away](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1133878326358171650).

Comment: check this similar question [Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846669/type-key-cannot-be-used-to-index-type-object) could be related to your issue. good luck ;)

Comment: Really helpful comments, thanks guys!

Comment: I think that it would be good if someone turns the comment into an answer (maybe @TchiteuMargiela?). That way this question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it using default arguments. TypeScript understands them just fine:

```
type GTitleProps = {
  children: any,
  color?: keyof typeof textColors,
};

const GTitle: React.FC<GTitleProps> = ({
  children,
  color = 'primary',
}) => (
  <Title color={textColors[color]}>
    {children}
  </Title>
);

export default GTitle;
```

Addendum: defaultProps will be [deprecated](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1133878326358171650) for function components.

Comment: Typescript understands them but not `eslint`.

Comment: @SalahAdDin With default rules? with me, eslint did not point out anything wrong

Comment: I found the `eslint` precise rule we need to use for default arguments.